# Converting binary string to IEEE 754 float

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me how to convert a 32-bit binary string to an IEEE 754 floating point value in Ruby?

For example, the binary string "01000001100101110011001100110011" (0x41973333) should convert to 18.9, but I can't figure out how to do this using Ruby.

I'm trying to get the same values returned by: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a fun one!

You need [String#unpack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) and [Array#pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) :

```
["01000001100101110011001100110011"].pack('B*').unpack('g').first
#=> 18.899999618530273
[18.9].pack('g').unpack('B*').first
#=> "01000001100101110011001100110011"
```

`'g'` is :

```
 g         | Float   | single-precision, network (big-endian) byte order
```

`'B*'` is multiple :

```
B         | String  | bit string (MSB first)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!